# Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопки , они подсвечивались не белым цветом, а другим

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
import messagebox



def on_closing():
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Выход из приложения", "Желаете выйти?"):
        win.destroy()

def start_window_1():
    new_window_1 = tk.Toplevel()
    new_window_1.title('Первое окно')
    new_window_1.geometry("450x400+150+250")
    new_window_1.configure(bg='green')
    new_window_1.iconphoto(False, photo)


def start_window_2():
    new_window_2 = tk.Toplevel()
    new_window_2.title('Второе окно')
    new_window_2.geometry("450x400+650+250")
    new_window_2.configure(bg='green')
    new_window_2.iconphoto(False, photo)


win = tk.Tk()
win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
photo = tk.PhotoImage(file='vkontakte.png')
win.iconphoto(False, photo)
win.title('Open')
win.geometry("900x600+180+150")
win.configure(background='#98ba1e')
win.resizable(width=False, height=False)

canvas = tk.Canvas(win,width=900, height=600, bg="#98ba1e", highlightthickness=0)
canvas.create_text(465,500,font="courier 20 bold italic", text="Программа создана @sw3ptop")
canvas.create_text(460,100,font = "courier 20 bold italic", text= "Выбирите кнопку:")



b1 = tk.Button(win,text = "Кнопка 1",width=15,height=8,bg = "#b3d929",command=start_window_1)
b2 = tk.Button(win,text = "Кнопка 2",width=15,height=8,bg = "#b3d929",command=start_window_2)

b1.pack(expand=True, ipadx=20, ipady=16)
b1.place(x=225,y=325)

b2.pack(expand=True, ipadx=20, ipady=16)
b2.place(x=585,y=325)

canvas.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Для изменения цвета кнопок в tkinter при их нажатии, нужно использовать опцию 'activebackground' для каждой кнопки, которую вы хотите изменить.

Пример:

```
button = tk.Button(text='Нажми меня', activebackground='red')
```

В данном примере при нажатии на кнопку ее цвет будет меняться на красный ('red').

Вы можете использовать эту опцию для всех ваших кнопок, например:

```
button1 = tk.Button(text='Окно 1', activebackground='red', command=start_window_1)
button2 = tk.Button(text='Окно 2', activebackground='blue', command=start_window_2)
```

Здесь кнопка button1 будет подсвечиваться красным цветом, а button2 - синим.